# How to easily migrate javascript version to new one for google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, deprecated

For years ago I had a hard time to do the google map with marks for my web.
I am impolanting ssl for paypal and I just checked and see the map does not work with htts:
so I entered google map for a solution and saw that the javascript has been deprectated and they recomend to upgrade to version3.
Is there an easy way to do or some tutorial, as I am so busy trying to integrate paypal and it was not easy the last time. Any tips?

This is how I have the map:

```
function createMarker(point,html) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", enter code herefunction() {
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    return marker;
  }

  // Display the map, with some controls and set the initial location 
  var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
  map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
  map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(36.51308543049258, -4.886341094970703), 13);

  // Set up three markers with info windows  

  var point = new GLatLng(36.50856685143835, -4.866085052490234);
  var marker = createMarker(point,'<div style="width:240px">Text here<a href="link here">Link<\/a><\/div>')
  map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [v2 reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/basics) and the [migration table](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3) to create a text file:

```
v2                v3
GMap2             google.maps.Map
GLatLng           google.maps.LatLng
GInfoWindow       google.maps.InfoWindow
GMapOptions       google.map.MapOptions
G_API_VERSION     google.maps.version
GPolyStyleOptions google.maps.PolygonOptions or google.maps.PolylineOptions
```

then run find/replace in one way or another:

```
   for func in `cat deprecated.txt`
     do
      grep -R $func /path/to/src
   done
```

**References**

- [Migrating to a newer version of PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732207/migrating-to-a-newer-version-of-php/732241#732241)
- [Advanced Find & Replace / Text Expand / Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905759/advanced-find-replace-text-expand-macros/9011995#9011995)
- [Conditional Awk hashmap match lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569913/conditional-awk-hashmap-match-lookup/13600904#13600904)
- [awk/sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string)
- [How do I move files from an old folder structure to new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556768/how-do-i-move-files-from-an-old-folder-structure-to-new/11319613#11319613)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715457/how-do-you-implement-a-dispatch-table-in-your-language-of-choice/13999292